# How to increase the vertical spacing between a Material UI FormLabel and Slider?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on a map with an image overlay that has adjustable opacity. Here is the component code:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { MapWithGroundOverlay } from './MapWithGroundOverlay'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box'
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel'
import Slider from '@material-ui/lab/Slider'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper'

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
  label: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  }
})

class AdjustableGroundoverlay extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.state = {opacity: 0.5}
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event, value) {
    this.setState(state => ({
      opacity: value
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid container className={this.props.classes.root} spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <MapWithGroundOverlay
            googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places`}
            loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
            containerElement={<div style={{ height: `600px` }} />}
            mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
            opacity={this.state.opacity}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Paper className={this.props.classes.paper}>
            <Box flexDirection="column">
              <FormLabel className={this.props.classes.label}>Overlay opacity</FormLabel>
              <Slider
                value={this.state.opacity}
                min={0}
                max={1}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </Box>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

AdjustableGroundoverlay.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

export default withStyles(styles)(AdjustableGroundoverlay)
```

The problem is that the `FormLabel` and `Slider` are too close together. If I hover over them, I see that the `Slider` has a negative margin of `-24px`:

[image]

It seems like the content of the `FormLabel` therefore sits directly on top of it:

[image]

I've tried to change the styling of the `Slider` by adding these `classes` to the component in accordance with https://material-ui.com/api/slider/#css:

```
          <Slider
            classes={{container: {marginTop: -12}}}
            value={this.state.opacity}
            min={0}
            max={1}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
```

but the spacing between the `FormLabel` and the `Slider` remains the same. Any idea what is wrong with this implementation?

**Update**
I've noticed in the console that there is this error:

[image]

I'm not sure why the key 'container' is not valid though since it is mentioned in https://material-ui.com/api/slider/#css.

Comment: have you tried adjusting the `line-height` at all?

Comment: I have, but this will change the spacing at the top as well, and what I really want is to just increase the spacing between the `FormLabel` and the `Slider`. I've added a `margin-top` of `-12px` (instead of `-24px`) to the `container` element of the `Slider` which looks OK to me; the only thing is how do I pass that into the Materialize UI style?

Comment: `container` needs to point at a class name (e.g. generated via `withStyles`) rather than style properties.

Comment: The [Simple Slider demo](https://material-ui.com/components/slider/#simple-slider) shows an example of adding padding to the Slider so that the label is spaced further up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by putting the slider in a `Box` with `mt` set to `1`:

```
      <Paper className={this.props.classes.paper}>
        <Box flexDirection="column">
          <FormLabel className={this.props.classes.label}>Overlay opacity</FormLabel>
          <Box mt={1}>
            <Slider
              value={this.state.opacity}
              min={0}
              max={1}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Paper>
```

Now there is more spacing between the label and the slider:

[image]